# Smooth integers with lower bound on $\omega(n)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisors-multiples, probabilistic-number-theory

Define $(b,c)$-smooth integers to be integers having all prime factors bigger than $c$ and smaller than $b$.

Probability a number is $(b,1)$-smooth is governed by the [Dickman function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22949/probability-of-being-b-smooth) while probability of number of prime divisors being at least $d$ is governed by the [Erdos-Kac formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Kac_theorem).

> 1. Is there a known distribution for $(b,c)$-smooth integers?
> 2. If we want the joint distribution of $(b,c)$-smooth integers with at least $d$ prime divisors then is there a formulation?

The reason I am asking is it seems we cannot have independence of smoothness and number of prime divisors since it quite does not make sense if the number of divisors is between $\log\log n+0.1\sqrt{\log\log n}$ and $\log\log n+0.2\sqrt{\log\log n}$ then the number cannot be $(b,1)$-smooth where $b=o(f(n))$ at a suitable function $f(n)$ with probability $1-o(1)$  and I do not know to capture this and identify $f(n)$ with independence assumption and identify involved probabilities.